# how i can delete a authcode include json file javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i have a question how i can delete a something include a json file ?

that's a example

my file name is `test.json`

this Before i delete auth code

```
{
  "auth": [
    {
      "test": 944037
    },
    {
      "tester": 261742
    }
  ]
}
```

i want for example delete a test

after i delete auth

```
{
  "auth": [
    {
      "tester": 261742
    }
  ]
}
```

**My All database like that**

Comment: that's not valid JSON, both input and output

Comment: @GrafiCode oh sorry, i fix it

Comment: This is several distinct problems, all well addressed on Stack Overflow: How to load a file, how to parse JSON, how to find and remove an element from a JavaScript array, how to encode an object as JSON, and how to write a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is unclear, are you struggling with

1. Reading the file?
2. Parsing and manipulating the JSON?
3. Saving the file?

Anyways, this code might help you:

```
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./test.json", (err, data) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(data.toString());

  // shift() removes the first object in 'auth'. Manipulate json however you wish.
  json["auth"].shift();

  // Remove second object (as asked by OP)
  json["auth"].pop();

  fs.writeFile("./test.json", JSON.stringify(json), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  });
});
```

It first reads the file, parses the contents into JSON. Then manipulates the JSON, and then saves the file, and will `console.log("The file was saved!");` if successful.

Comment: hey, thanks but i have question if i want delete a second object ?

Comment: @yousef You can use `json["auth"].pop();`.  Keep in mind, `json["auth"]` is an array of objects at this point. I updated my answer.